# Assign predefined numbers to values of column rows in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, loops, for-loop, dataframe

lets say i have a dataframe

```
   C                 D
agree           Average
agree           agree
strongly agree  disagree
disagree        agree
```

what i want to do is to assign numbers to C column values like this ?

```
 C  D
 1  3
 1  1
 2  0
 0  1
```

i can use [map](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) for single column but if there are more than one column how do i change values to numbers without writing individually for every column (i know i could use for loops but the problem is that how would i apply it in here)

anyone know how to do this?

i tried to use a for loop

```
def assignNumbers(df):


for i in df:

    dftest= df[i].map({'Average':3, 'Agree':1, 'Disagree':0, 'Strongly Agree':2})

return dftest
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be

```
df.replace({'Average': 3, 'agree': 1, 'disagree': 0, 'strongly agree': 2})
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [`pd.factorize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.factorize.html) for a generalized solution (e.g. if you don't know how many categories you'll have beforehand).

```
pd.DataFrame(pd.factorize(df.values.T.reshape(-1,))[0].reshape(df.shape[1], -1), index=df.columns).T

    C   D
0   0   3
1   0   0
2   1   2
3   2   0
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use a type of category and `cat.codes`:

```
df.unstack().astype('category').cat.codes.unstack(0)
```

```
   C  D
0  1  0
1  1  1
2  3  2
3  2  1
```

If you actually want to match your output, and not just assign unique values to each variable, you can create a `CategoricalDtype` and define the order.

```
from pandas.api.types import CategoricalDtype
cat = CategoricalDtype(
    categories=['disagree', 'agree', 'strongly agree', 'Average'], ordered=True
)

df.stack().astype(cat).cat.codes.unstack(1)
```

```
   C  D
0  1  3
1  1  1
2  2  0
3  0  1
```